# windows TAPI api through java

Tags: java, windows, tapi

I want to use TAPI API which comes with Windows implementation ex. Tapi32.dll 
Does anybody have any prior experience of using TAPI Api in Windows with Java , please help

Comment: This is a question that should be solved by using google to find a tutorial, not by asking on StackOverflow. Writing tutorials is definitely a too broad thing to ask for.

Comment: I have googled a lot but hardly found anything moreover the GJTapi and other implementations are vendor specific.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to avoid doing this since you're losing portability. Try to use a local server instead with a minimal native piece of code to wrap your calls.

Comment: But the native code would require to be understood and call through java , moreover the struct types or object types require conversion to/fro c & Java has a long learning curve